# Как выполнить команду в фоне, чтобы вернуть себе ответ?

Tags: python, linux

Допустим, кусок кода:

```
w = subprocess.Popen('command', shell = True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
o, e = w.communicate()
print o
print e
```

Скрипт дальше не продолжить работу, пока не закончит выполнять команду.
Как сделать, чтобы он дальше работал, а когда придет ответ от команды, то показать?

Answer (score 2):

Если чтобы дальше работал и вернул ответ, то
стоит это завернуть в отдельную нить  (Thread).